# Can a local variable exist before a combined declaration/assignment?

Tags: c, variables

I'm currently trying to debug a small C program whose general structure looks like this:

```
int some_function(...) {
    ...
    size_t buf_len = some_other_function(...)
    ...
}

main() {
    ...
    int foo = some_function(...)
    ...
}
```

I've set a breakpoint at `some_function()` (using lldb). However, if I inspect the stack frame at this breakpoint it shows the variable `buf_len` already existing with the local scope and even having an arbitrary(?) value. How is this possible if the variable is not declared anywhere before this function?

Comment: A stack frame contains the args passed in *and* the local variables and some other stuff.

Comment: @babon Do you mean I am misunderstanding what setting a breakpoint at a function means? I thought that was basically a shortcut to stop at the first line of that function, where the stack frame should know the function args, but not the new variables created in that function. Is that wrong?

Comment: As far as I remember my compiler course, the stack frame size is computed at compile time. From that, it is possible that `buf_length` already has a "reserved position" in the stack frame. That is, when you call `some_function` the stack frame is allocated (i.e. sp increased), and lldb already prints the location of `buf_length`. To be confirmed by someone else, this is just guessing...

Comment: When you say "first line of a function", aren't you already inside that function? :) And you can't call a function without an activation record / stack frame (which roughly means all the args and local variables bundled together).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [§6.2.4/6 of the C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4p6):

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type,
>   its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is
>   associated until execution of that block ends in any way.

So it should come as no surprise that `buf_len` is visible in the debugger the moment execution enters `some_function()`.

Comment: Ok, so I was indeed misunderstanding the creation of the stack frame. Guess it's time do dig a bit deeper into the C specification:) Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: This is for standard. But if the variable is optimized the OP will get the surprise to don't find any variable in the stack frame.

Comment: @Frankie_C -- I fail to see your point. OP asked about a variable that was visible when not expected, not about an expected variable that was missing. This answer addresses OP's posted question. Notions about stack frames, etc. are _implementation details_ which might be needed to explain behavior in some instances, but not this one, which is neatly explained for all conforming implementations by the Standard.

Comment: @DavidBowling Follow up question: Do you know where the listed value of that variable is coming from? I thought it was something already present at its memory location, but it seems to always be small int (sometimes 6, sometimes 14), i.e. not really a random value?

Comment: @mxgx -- The value is indeterminate until an initializer is reached or an assignment is made.

Comment: My point was simply an addition, not a critic to your answer. Anyway we should consider that the OP approached the question from a practical side, while debugging the code, more than from the pure standard implementation that describes the lexical and semantic rules, apart from which the case I signaled should avoid another question: "why I don't find the variable? The standard says it must be there...".

Comment: I found both of your answers very helpful. My takeaway is to consult the standard first if my expectations don't match the actual outcome, but keep in mind that any specific implementation might still deviate from the standard in subtle ways.

Comment: @Frankie_C -- Ah. Sensible enough. Interestingly, OP question for a `size_t` variable is straightforward using the Standard, but if instead there was a VLA in the function, e.g. `char arr[x];`, it is not guaranteed by the Standard to exist before the declaration is encountered (the Standard says it does not exist until declaration). GDB, at least, shows such symbols to exist before declaration when compiled with GCC. Explanation here must involve details of one or both.

Comment: A VLA can be created on stack or in dynamic memory. The decision depends on the memory required and how the compiler manage it. It can use an `alloca()` call to reserve space after function entry or allocate memory on the heap. In any case the frame will show a variable that in the first case can be the whole array, in the latter will be a pointer to the heap memory. Anyway you'll find a reference to the array from function start. Of course the behavior is compiler/architecture dependent.

Comment: @Frankie_C -- yet the Standard explicitly says that VLAs do not exist until declaration. I note that in a quick test similar to OP code, but with a VLA: `int x = 5;  char arr[x];`, GDB recognizes the symbol `arr` after entering the function, but the value held by `arr` (`p arr`) changes after the declaration is reached. This seems to suggest that the VLA does not yet exist, but merely that the symbol is recognized by GDB.

Comment: Or that the real memory is allocated only after the flow reach the declaration... ;)

Comment: @mxgx -- "My takeaway is to consult the standard first..., but keep in mind that any specific implementation might still deviate from the standard...." Not a bad takeaway, but note that a conforming implementation must not deviate from the Standard. Yet there are plenty of cases where the Standard explicitly leaves something up to the implementation (these must be explicitly documented by the implementation), and there are also compiler extensions to keep you on your toes ;)

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness let clarify a point: a compliant compiler **cannot deviate from standard**, meaning that during the lexical and semantic analysis all rules of the standard must be fully respected. But the code generation is independent and no restrictions exist apart from that the code execution must produce output compliant with source flow. So if memory space exist or not when functions starts is indepent from any warning or error generated during source analysis. Current code generation technologies, or at least those I know, works the way you've seen while debugging.

Answer (score 5):

During compilation each variable is added to the symbol table.
For this reason any reference to a variable will resolve only if it was already declared, and inserted in the symbol table. If you reference a variable before its declaration you'll get an error of undefined reference.

But the space for all the automatic variables is allocated **all-in-one** in the stack during the function prolog (i.e. in IA32-64 architecture the space required by all automatic variables is obtained subtracting that space to the stack pointer register in the stack frame). The required space is computed by the compiler by summing the memory space required for all automatic variables present in the symbol table for that function.

Practically when stack frame is created on function entry all automatic variables are there, even if used after.

In some cases the variables **are not allocated** if the compiler optimize them out, the compiler optimizing the code choose a different way to use the variable suppressing it (i.e. using a register or simplifying the flow and removing intermediate storage).

Answer (score 2):

A stack frame contains the args passed in along with the local variables and some other stuff. Look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), especially the "Structure" section. A breakpoint can not make you stop just between two functions. At a function call, a stack frame is one of the first things created.

Comment: This doesn't really explain it. An implementation might allocate space for the variable as the variable is declared (on x86* it would be by decreasing stack pointer by sizeof variable). It's just that in practice all implementations allocate space for locals at once in the function prolog.